# Laravel broadcasting, private channels not working

Tags: php, laravel, chat, pusher

I have been searching for a way to implement a real-time chat in Laravel, and this solution
https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel/
was the closest I found to what I needed.

I have implemented it as is and it's working to some extent, but to be honest I have no idea why it's working and how to debug what is not working.

When using private channels, the Pusher debug console is receiving the messages with the correct session numbers.

**1. It's only working with public channels, if I replace the following:**

In the MessageSent event, "PrivateChannel" by "Channel"

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
  return [
    new PrivateChannel('session.'.$this->session_code),
  ];
}
```

In the JS code, "private" by "channel" ("private" will be underlined by the IDE with the message "Instance member is not accessible")

```
window.Echo.private('session.'+this.session_code)
  .listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
    this.messages.push({
      message: e.message.message,
      sender: e.user
    });
  });
```

**2. It's working without `php artisan serve`, I have a virtual host on my local system and a laravel-websockets script running on my staging site, but it's not connected and everything I tried doesn't make a difference**

bootstrap.js

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: {{KEY}},
    cluster: 'eu',
    // forceTLS: true,
    encrypted: true,
    // wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    // wsPort: 8888,
});
```

broadcasting.php

```
'options' => [
  'cluster' => 'eu',
  'encrypted' => true,
    //'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    //'port' => 8888,
    //'scheme' => 'https',
    //'useTLS' => true,
],
```

**3. BroadcastServiceProvider fires normally, but nothing seems to be running through channels.php, the condition I put in there doesn't affect that anybody who can access a specific chat page can see its content.**

BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'auth']);
    
    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

routes/channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('session.{code}', function ($user, $code) {
    $session = ChatSession::where('code',$code)->first();
    return in_array($user->id, $session->participant_ids);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding a dot at the beginning of your event name in your  `session` channel listeners

```
window.Echo.private('session.'+this.session_code)
  .listen('.MessageSent', (e) => {
```

Do the same in case of presence channels

Comment: Just tried it, no change... Isn't the problem that the **routes/channels.php** file is being ignored?

Comment: when using private or presence channel laravel echo must authenticate. Try adding 
 `authEndpoint:  'http://yoursite.test/broadcasting/auth'` to your window.Echo config object

Comment: If I console.log() the window.Echo.private object, I can see `authEndpoint: "/broadcasting/auth"` without having declared it, I did try adding it anyway and it still doesn't change anything